# Different Shell Context Menu versus windows explorer context menu

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, shell-extensions

Hi I have implementation of the IShellFolder com interface in my .NET program when I have get all items from shell context menu. But I have a problem where my tracking shell context menu have some different items versus explorer shell context menu. In the pictures below you have seen that in my program I do not view Open in program sub menu. I have only one item "Open in program". And in my context menu missing Open in Notepad++ and I have in addition some other items like 7-zip item and submenu and CRC SHA from 7-zip program too.

The first picture is shell context menu from windows explorer and the second picture is from my shell context menu code.

Can you tell me where I have an error? Thank you very much.

[image: Shell Context Menu from windows explorer]

[image: Shell Context Menu from my code]

And this is my code:

```
private ContextMenu CreateFileContextMenu(FileInfo[] files, Point location)
{
    Win32APICaller.CoInitializeEx(IntPtr.Zero, COINIT.MULTITHREADED);
    IShellFolder parentFolder = GetParentFolder(files[0].DirectoryName);
    IntPtr[] pidls = this.GetPIDLs(parentFolder, files);

    IntPtr pMenu = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr iContextMenuPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr iContextMenuPtr2 = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr iContextMenuPtr3 = IntPtr.Zero;

    if (pidls != null)
    {
        IContextMenu contextMenu;
        if (this.GetContextMenuInterfaces(parentFolder, pidls, out contextMenu, out iContextMenuPtr))
        {
            pMenu = Win32APICaller.CreatePopupMenu();

            Marshal.QueryInterface(iContextMenuPtr, ref IID_IContextMenu2, out iContextMenuPtr2);
            Marshal.QueryInterface(iContextMenuPtr, ref IID_IContextMenu3, out iContextMenuPtr3);

            contextMenu2 = (IContextMenu2)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(iContextMenuPtr2, typeof(IContextMenu2));
            contextMenu3 = (IContextMenu3)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(iContextMenuPtr3, typeof(IContextMenu3));

            int nResult = contextMenu.QueryContextMenu(pMenu, 0, 1, 30000, CMF.EXPLORE | CMF.CANRENAME | CMF.NORMAL | CMF.INCLUDESTATIC | CMF.EXTENDEDVERBS);
            int count = Win32APICaller.GetMenuItemCount(pMenu);

            //contextMenu3.QueryContextMenu(pMenu, 0, 1, 30000, /*CMF.EXPLORE | CMF.NORMAL |*/ CMF.EXTENDEDVERBS);

            count = Win32APICaller.GetMenuItemCount(pMenu);
            Win32APICaller.SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_INITMENUPOPUP, pMenu, 0);
            uint nSelected = Win32APICaller.TrackPopupMenuEx(pMenu, 0x0100, location.X, location.Y, this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
       }
   }
}

private IntPtr[] GetPIDLs(IShellFolder parentFolder, FileInfo[] files)
{
    if (parentFolder != null)
    {
        IntPtr[] pidls = new IntPtr[files.Length];
        for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = files[index];

            uint pchEaten = 0;
            SFGAO pdwAttributes = 0;
            IntPtr pPIDL = IntPtr.Zero;
            int nResult = parentFolder.ParseDisplayName(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, fileInfo.Name, ref pchEaten, out pPIDL, ref pdwAttributes);
            if (nResult == 0)
            {
                pidls[index] = pPIDL;
            }
        }

        return pidls;
    }

    return null;
}

private IShellFolder GetParentFolder(string folderName)
{
    IShellFolder desktopFolder = this.GetDektopFolder();
    if (desktopFolder != null)
    {
        IntPtr pPIDL = IntPtr.Zero;
        uint pchEaten = 0;
        SFGAO pdwAttributes = 0;
        int nResult = desktopFolder.ParseDisplayName(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, folderName, ref pchEaten, out pPIDL, ref pdwAttributes);
        if (nResult == 0)
        {
            IntPtr pStrRet = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(260 * 2 + 4);
            Marshal.WriteInt32(pStrRet, 0, 0);
            nResult = desktopFolder.GetDisplayNameOf(pPIDL, SHGNO.FORPARSING, pStrRet);
            StringBuilder strFolder = new StringBuilder(260);
            Win32APICaller.StrRetToBuf(pStrRet, pPIDL, strFolder, 260);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pStrRet);
            pStrRet = IntPtr.Zero;

            IntPtr pUnknownParentFolder = IntPtr.Zero;
            nResult = desktopFolder.BindToObject(pPIDL, IntPtr.Zero, ref IID_IShellFolder, out pUnknownParentFolder);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pPIDL);
            if (nResult == 0)
            {
                return (IShellFolder)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(pUnknownParentFolder, typeof(IShellFolder));
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private IShellFolder GetDektopFolder()
{
    IntPtr pUnknownDesktopFolder = IntPtr.Zero;

    int nResult = Win32APICaller.SHGetDesktopFolder(out pUnknownDesktopFolder);
    if (nResult == 0)
        return (IShellFolder)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(pUnknownDesktopFolder, typeof(IShellFolder));
    else
        return null;
}

private bool GetContextMenuInterfaces(IShellFolder parentFolder, IntPtr[] pidls, out IContextMenu contextMenu, out IntPtr contextMenuPtr)
{
    int nResult = parentFolder.GetUIObjectOf(this.Handle, (uint)pidls.Length, pidls, IID_IContextMenu, IntPtr.Zero, out contextMenuPtr);
    contextMenu = null;

    if (nResult == 0)
    {
        contextMenu = (IContextMenu)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(contextMenuPtr, typeof(IContextMenu));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (this.contextMenu3 != null)
    {
        this.contextMenu3.HandleMenuMsg2((uint)m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam, m.Result);
    }
    else if (this.contextMenu2 != null)
    {
        this.contextMenu2.HandleMenuMsg((uint)m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add CMF_EXTENDEDVERBS?

Comment: For different file types, different locations, the context menu will differ. What file type and file explorer location are you talking about?

Comment: Make sure your window handles the menu messages like `WM_INITMENUPOPUP` and passes them to `IContextMenu2::HandleMenuMsg`.

Comment: Both choices has been for the same file and location. I have tried CMF_EXTENDEDVERBS and only one difference is int the context menu that the context menu has one item added.

Comment: This can be pretty complex and depends how your IShellFolder is implemented, what type of items it has (SFGAO flags, FILESYSTEM or not, etc.), also the parent item, etc. How do you create the IContextMenu/2/3, do you answer IQueryAssociations, etc. Do you have a minimal complete reproducing code?

Comment: In fact, with an IShellFolder, you're not supposed to create the menu yourself, but call SHCreateDefaultContextMenu when asked for IContextMenu/2/3 and let it do the hard work for you.

Comment: I have edit my code with full example. And when I have added WndProc method, the submenu Open in Program is the same like the explorer submenu, but the Notepad++ isn't in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the pictures below you have seen that in my program I do not view
> Open in program sub menu. I have only one item "Open in program".

[image]

**The reason for this is that these submenus are delay-generated (which explains why they don’t contain anything interesting when you expand them) and owner-drawn.**

So you need to [handle messages associated with owner-drawn menu items](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040927-00/?p=37733).

After that you will get what you expected like this:

[image]

The following is an Win32 C++ sample code you can refer to:

```
#define SCRATCH_QCM_FIRST 1
#define SCRATCH_QCM_LAST  0x7FFF

IContextMenu2* g_pcm2;
IContextMenu3* g_pcm3;

//...

void OnContextMenu(HWND hwnd, int xPos, int yPos)
{
    WCHAR pszFilePath[] = L"C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\test1.txt";
    IShellFolder* psfDesktop = NULL;
    ITEMIDLIST* id = 0;
    LPCITEMIDLIST idChild = 0;
    IContextMenu* pcm = NULL;
    int iCmdTemp = 0;

    POINT pt = { xPos, yPos };
    if (pt.x == -1 && pt.y == -1) {
        pt.x = pt.y = 0;
        ClientToScreen(hwnd, &pt);
    }

    SHParseDisplayName(pszFilePath, 0, &id, 0, 0);
    SHBindToParent(id, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)& psfDesktop, &idChild);

    psfDesktop->GetUIObjectOf(hwnd, 1, (const ITEMIDLIST **)&idChild, __uuidof(IContextMenu), NULL, (void **)&pcm);

    if (pcm) {
        HMENU hmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
        if (hmenu) {
            if (SUCCEEDED(pcm->QueryContextMenu(hmenu, 0,
                SCRATCH_QCM_FIRST, SCRATCH_QCM_LAST,
                CMF_NORMAL))) {

                pcm->QueryInterface(IID_IContextMenu2, (void**)& g_pcm2);
                pcm->QueryInterface(IID_IContextMenu3, (void**)& g_pcm3);

                int iCmd = TrackPopupMenuEx(hmenu, TPM_RETURNCMD,
                    pt.x, pt.y, hwnd, NULL);
                if (g_pcm2) {
                    g_pcm2->Release();
                    g_pcm2 = NULL;
                }
                if (g_pcm3) {
                    g_pcm3->Release();
                    g_pcm3 = NULL;
                }
                if (iCmd > 0) {
                    CMINVOKECOMMANDINFOEX info = { 0 };
                    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
                    info.fMask = 0x00004000;
                    info.hwnd = hwnd;
                    iCmdTemp = iCmd - SCRATCH_QCM_FIRST;
                    info.lpVerb = MAKEINTRESOURCEA(iCmdTemp);
                    info.lpVerbW = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(iCmdTemp);
                    info.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
                    pcm->InvokeCommand((LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO)& info);
                }

            }
            DestroyMenu(hmenu);
        }
        pcm->Release();
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

    if (g_pcm3) {
        LRESULT lres;
        if (SUCCEEDED(g_pcm3->HandleMenuMsg2(message, wParam, lParam, &lres))) {
            return lres;
        }
    }
    else if (g_pcm2) {
        if (SUCCEEDED(g_pcm2->HandleMenuMsg(message, wParam, lParam))) {
            return 0;
        }
    }


    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
        xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
        OnContextMenu(hWnd, xPos, yPos);
        break;
//...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response, I have programming the WndProc method and the submenu Open with has been filled now. But I have a problem that I don't view the Open with Notepad++ and the 7-zip isn't in the explorer context menu but in my context yes.

Comment: @xasd89 If you are talking about a .txt file, there is a "Edit with Notepad++" and in Open with submenu, there is a "Notepad". No such "*Open with Notepad++*" menu or submenu for me.

Comment: I am sorry, yes I think the "Edit with Notepad++" as it shown on my screenshot in original question.

Comment: @xasd89 Sorry for the delay. I view "Edit with Notepad++" in the explorer context menu. And there is a Registry entry for it: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\ANotepad++64`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason why could not view the Edit with Notepad++ item in the Context Menu. I need compile my code as the **x64 architecture**. And when I have done this the context menu view the Edit with Notepad++ and the 7-zip items missing.

**When I find on the internet **I have found that depends on the program architecture** and I have registered the Notepad++ in the context menu as **x64 architecture only**.**